# Promise response argument getting lost

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm learning browser-provided promises and I'm having difficulty with the response argument getting lost and not coming through. This is my code:

```html
/* uploads a resource to the given server and runs the callback function when done */
function upload(serverUrl, resource, successfulCallback, failCallback) {
    console.log("upload successfulCallback: ", successfulCallback);
    console.log("upload failCallback: ", failCallback);
 var jqxhr = $.ajax({
  url: serverUrl,
  method: "POST",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: encode(resource),
  headers: {
            Accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            Prefer: "return=minimal"
        }
 }).done(function() {
        console.log("Upload done, jqxhr: ", jqxhr);
  successfulCallback(jqxhr);
 }).fail(function(err) {
  console.log("upload failed: " + err.responseText);
  failCallback(jqxhr, err);
 });
}

function validate(endpoint, resource) {
    var parameters = {
        "resourceType": "Parameters",
        "parameter": [{
            "name": "resource",
            "resource": resource            
        }]        
    };
     
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("Made new promise, resolve function is: ", resolve);
        console.log("Made new promise, reject function is: ", reject);
        upload(endpoint + '/' + resource.resourceType + "/$validate", parameters, resolve, reject);
    });
}
```

And this is how I make use of it:

```html
    validate("http://fhir3.healthintersections.com.au/open", decode(leftFhirView.getValue()))
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log("It worked! '", response, "'");
        }, function(error) {
            console.error("Failed validation!", error.stack);
        });
```

Here's the debugging output I get when I run

```
main.js:45 Made new promise, resolve function is:  u() { [native code] }
main.js:46 Made new promise, reject function is:  v() { [native code] }
main.js:14 upload successfulCallback:  u() { [native code] }
main.js:15 upload failCallback:  v() { [native code] }
main.js:27 Upload done, jqxhr:  Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", <snip>
main.js:196 It worked! '  '
```

As you can see, somewhere between successfulCallback(jqxhr) and the response function, my jqxhr turns into two spaces. What is happening?

Comment: actually, it didn't turn into two spaces, it turned into an empty string - those two spaces are put there by console.log - try `typeof response` just to see what it is you're resovling - `responseText` is an empty string, but your code should still resolve to the jqxhr object logged at line 27

Comment: You should create the `new Promise` right inside of `upload` and `return` it from there, so that you don't have to deal with callback parameters at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by returning the jQuery promise all the way through the validate function.

Answer (score 0):

To explain what @Jaromanda X said in the comment.

You are trying to resolve a `Promise` inside of another `Promise`. The original `Promise` object will not be passed to `then`'s callback. Instead, it will be the reponse text in the original `Promise` object.

In this case, `jqxhr` is the original `Promise` (`$.ajax` returns a `Promise` object), and its response text is `""`. That is why you get an empty string.

According to the documentation by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve), your code works same as the example below

```
var original = Promise.resolve(true);
var cast = Promise.resolve(original);
cast.then(function(v) {
  console.log(v); // true
});
```

**Upated on 11/14/16

Pointed out by @Bergi, `jqxhr` is not a instance of `Promise`, but a JQuery deferred object with a property `then`(promise-like). However, `Promise.then` would look for `jqxhr.then`, which resolves promise asynchronously if there is  such a property.

Comment: Sorry, still confused. My upload is not failing, so why is the response text coming into play?

I'm also not returning the jqxhr promise inside the upload() function but rather using callbacks (so promises don't get too complicated).

Comment: Actually, I wasn't making that point - I can't actually see why the OP is  getting, essentially, responseText in the then rather than the resolved object `jqxhr`

Comment: @Vadi Yes, you are not returning `jqxhr`, but `jqxhr.reponseText` becomes the param of the callback function in `then`. `successfulCallback(jqxhr)` is called after `jqxhr` is resolved. Since `jqxhr instanceof Promise === true`, the reference of `response` param in `.then(function(response) {...})` is really `jqxhr.reponseText`. Check out this [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

Comment: @Z.Z. `jqXhr instanceof Promise` is false, but it's a jQuery deferred with a `then` method so it is going to be assimilated *like* a promise

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, i was wrong, would `Promise.resolve(jqxhr)` would resolve `jqxhr` as a plain object or a `Promise`?

Comment: @Z.Z. it would try to call `jqxhr.then`, which resolves the promise asynchronously given it's a thenable (promise-like).

Comment: @Bergi, that makes sense. Thanks!